# Trying to use df to find the shortest distance to all nodes from a source node in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, shortest-path, dijkstra

```
def networkDelay(self,times,n,k):
    graph=collections.defaultdict(list)
    for u,v,w in times:
        graph[u].append((v,w))
    dist = [sys.maxsize] * (n + 1)
    dist[k] = 0
    visited=set()
    def dfs(graph,u,prev):
        visited.add((prev,u))
        for v,w in graph[u]:
            dist[v] = min(dist[v], dist[u] + w)
            if (u,v) not in visited:
                dfs(graph,v,u)
    dfs(graph,k,k)
    return dist[1:]
```

```
times[i] = (ui, vi, wi). //edge

times = [[2,1,1],[2,3,1],[3,4,1]], n = 4, k = 2
```

The above code works for almost all of the cases, but
failing for below test

Input

```
times= [[2,7,63],[4,3,60],[1,3,53],[5,6,100],[1,4,40],[4,7,95],[4,6,97],[3,4,68],[1,7,75],[2,6,84],[1,6,27],[5,3,25],[6,2,2],[3,7,57],[5,4,2],[7,1,53],[5,7,35],[4,1,60],[5,2,95],[3,5,28],[6,1,61],[2,5,28]]
n=7,k=3
```

Result

```
dist[]=[90, 123, 0, 30, 28, 117, 57]. // 123 should be 119
```

Could someone help identifying what's wrong with the above program?

Comment: You have a small failing example. What have you found out during debugging?

Answer (score 0):

```
def networkDelay(self,times,n,k):
    graph=collections.defaultdict(list)
    for u,v,w in times:
        graph[u].append((v,w))
    dist = [sys.maxsize] * (n + 1)
    dist[k] = 0
    def dfs(graph,u):
        for v,w in graph[u]:
            if dist[u]+w<dist[v]:
                dist[v] = dist[u] + w
                dfs(graph,v)
    dfs(graph,k)
    mx=max(dist[1:])
    return mx if mx<sys.maxsize else -1
```